# I marked fields as mandatory on page layout. but it is not marked as mandatory on detail page

Tags: administration, developer

I have scenario, I marked some custom fields mandatory to register a lead and it's working fine with new Lead. But after registering Lead, when I go to detail page of that Lead, there is no single field marked as mandatory. Same issue goes with Opportunity. I checked with SchemaBuilder, Page Layout and Field property. It's same as in the sandbox.
Any assistance would be highly appreciated.
I recently deploy into production, it was working fine in sandbox.

Comment: Have you marked the field mandatory from filed permissions or have you marked it mandatory on a specific layout ?

Comment: Yes, I marked the field mandatory on page layout as well.

Comment: On the detail page, fields are not displayed as mandatory. Fields are shown as mandatory only on Edit page. Not sure, what are you checking for in detail page.

Comment: Yes, That's right. It working now.

Thanks.